# How can I add image at the footer of Office (Word, Excel, Powerpoint, etc) documents?

Tags: image, addition, footer, document

I need to programmatically(C#, .NET) add QR code as an image in the footer of some MS Document files(word, excel, powerpoint, etc) and other documents types like pdf. How can I do that? Is there a generic way to do that?

Comment: Which utility or library are you using to make documents from C#.Net. What have you tried already? Please be more precise

Comment: I am not making these documents. They are there. I just want to upload them by my .NET application to SharePoint, and before doing that, I want to add a QR Code (from some metadata of the document) in the footer. I have not tried anything, but google search doesn't help me much. So I am asking here. FYI, my application is VSTO add-in.